# What is the difference between "&&" and ";" when chaining commands

Tags: bash, shell

What is the difference between the following methods of chaining commands?

```
cmd1; cmd2
cmd1 && cmd2
```

Answer (score 197, accepted):

Assume there is `command1 && command2`.

In this case `command2` will be executed if and only if `command1` returned zero exit status.

`;` is just a command separator. Thus `command2` will be executed whatever `command1` returned.

```
$> [[ "a" = "b" ]] && echo ok 

$> [[ "a" = "b" ]]; echo ok 
ok
```

Comment: Similarly, `command1 || command2` can be used to run `command2` only if `command1` returned a nonzero exit status.

Comment: Note that the return value of the full expression is the return value of the last command that was executed.

Comment: Weird actually.. if command1 returns zero, then command2 is executed? Thinking about lazy evaluation, an `&&` should not even look at the second argument when the first is already 0 - the result will be 0 anyway.

Comment: @Konerak: With exit codes, `0` indicates success, or `true` while anything else is `false`, so it's sort of reversed compared to "ordinary" booleans.

Comment: @hammar that seems rather unfortunate. A more logical choice would be 0 || next_step to indicate success of the previous step, in line with lazy evaluation of logical or.

Answer (score 39):

`cmd1; cmd2` executes `cmd1`, then `cmd2`, no matter what. It it exactly equivalent to putting `cmd1` and `cmd2` on separate lines¹. The return status of this compound command is that of `cmd2`.

`cmd1 && cmd2` executes `cmd1`. Then, if the exit status of `cmd1` is zero, `cmd2` is executed. The return status of this compound command is that of `cmd1` if it is nonzero (so `cmd2` didn't run), and that of `cmd2` otherwise (if it ran).

`if cmd1; then cmd2; fi` is mostly equivalent to `cmd1 && cmd2`. The main difference is that the version with `if` returns 0 if `cmd1` returns a nonzero status.

A command returns 0 to indicate success, and a nonzero error code (between 1 and 255, usually between 1 and 125 as higher values have other meanings) to indicate failure. Thus `cmd1; cmd2` means “execute these commands in sequence no matter what”, whereas `cmd1 && cmd2` means “execute these commands, but stop immediately if the first command fails”.

You can tell the shell to enter “exit on error” mode by running `set -e`. In this mode, the shell exits as soon as any command returns a nonzero status, except in conditional constructs (the left side of `&&` or `||`, the condition part of `if` and `while`). Thus, under `set -e`, `;` (or a newline) is effectively equivalent to `&&`².

¹  <sub>In terms on control flow, that is. Newlines and semicolons are executed in exactly the same way, but they aren't parsed in exactly the same way, so e.g. `alias ls=true; ls` executes `ls` and not `true` because the parser performs alias resolution on `ls` before it executes the alias definition.</sub> 
¹  <sub>This isn't to say you can blindly replace `&&` by `;` if you've added `set -e`. For example, `;` has lower precedence than `&&`, so `cmd1 && cmd2 || cmd3` is equivalent to `set -e; { cmd1; cmd2; } || cmd3`. Also, `set -e` interacts badly with subshells — the details would derail this answer too far.</sub>

Comment: *"as higher values have other meanings"* what do they mean? If I'm writing my own program, is there any standard error naming (numbering?) convention?

Comment: @rahmu Shells use error codes 126 and 127 to indicate that the program could not be started at all, and 128+N to indicate that the program died with signal N. So from a shell, the only status codes that unambiguously show that the program ran to completion are 0 to 126 (and 128, if you really want to confuse readers).

Comment: @Gilles: I don't fully agree with the last sentence. Try `echo $(set -e; { false; (exit 2) } && true; echo $?)` vs `echo $(set -e; { false && (exit 2) } && true; echo $?)` ;)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Ok, yes, `set -e` and subshells together can be funky.

Comment: Note: `cmd1; cmd2` is not necessarily the same as `cmd1<newline>cmd2`. Cases that come to mind are when `cmd1` affects the shell parsing like `alias` commands or commands that change the localisation settings. For instance, `alias foo=bar;foo` is not necessarily the same as `alias foo=bar<newline>foo`.

Answer (score 22):

The first line will execute one command after another, irrespective of whether the first one succeeded or not. The second line is an example of shell logic: it will only execute the second command if the first one succeeded. This is because `&&` is logical `and`. Therefore, if the first command fails, the logical state of the entire line is known to be false and there is no need to evaluate the second command.

Answer (score 4):

More practical, there's a difference between

```
cd /backup/old; rm -rf -- *
```

and

```
cd /backup/old && rm -rf -- *
```

. Besides it's a stupid way, the first one will remove your whole filesystem (or $HOME, depending how it's called) because it runs `rm` regardless of whether the `cd` succeeded or not.

Comment: While your answer is correct, it's dangerous if a user ran it to see the difference for himself.  Why not "echo something" instead?

Comment: I trust people not to do obviously stupid things. This is a +/- example I heard first hand.

Comment: @RandyStegbauer Because people who will run this do not deserve to have files in their filesystem.